# Why does commands of buttons on tkinter doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm trying to create turtles racing but with different windows at the same time. The play and exit buttons work but when I pick a color, nothing happens. Here's some of my code.

P.S I didn't add all of them because stack overflow wouldn't allow many codes

```
#miscellaneous
play = True
player = ' '
```

so these are the functions

```
def hide_frames():
    frame1.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame3.pack_forget() 
    
def chosen1():
    player = 't1'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
           
def chosen2():    
    player = 't2'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
        
def chosen3():
    player = 't3'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
      
def chosen4():
    player = 't4'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
        
def chosen5():
    player = 't5'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
            
def chosen6():
    player = 't6'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
            
def chosen7():
    player = 't7'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
            
def chosen8():
    player = 't8'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()
        
def chosen9():
    player = 't9'
    hide_frames
    frame3.pack()   

def playy():
    hide_frames()
    play = False
    frame2.pack()
```

and these are my buttons

```
    button1 = Button (frame2, text = 'green', fg = 'green', command = chosen1)
    button2 = Button (frame2, text = 'blue', fg = 'blue', command = chosen2)
    button3 = Button (frame2, text = 'red', fg = 'red', command = chosen3)
    button4 = Button (frame2, text = 'yellow', fg = 'yellow', command = chosen4)
    button5 = Button (frame2, text = 'orange', fg = 'orange', command = chosen5)
    button6 = Button (frame2, text = 'indigo', fg = 'indigo', command = chosen6)
    button7 = Button (frame2, text = 'violet', fg = 'violet', command = chosen7)
    button8 = Button (frame2, text = 'maroon', fg = 'maroon', command = chosen8)
    button9 = Button (frame2, text = 'magenta', fg = 'magenta', command = chosen9)
```

I already pack() the buttons but I didn't include it here because it will be too long

```
def start():
    t1.goto(400, 400)
    t2.goto(400, 300)
    t3.goto(400, 200)
    t4.goto(400, 100)
    t5.goto(400, 0)
    t6.goto(400, -100)
    t7.goto(400, -200)
    t8.goto(400, -300)
    t9.goto(400, -400)

#buttons
play_button = Button(frame1, text = 'Play', command = playy).pack(side = TOP)
exit_button = Button(frame1, text = 'Quit', command = root.quit).pack(side = TOP)
label = Label(frame2, text = 'please pick your color')
label.pack()
start_button = Button(frame3, text = 'START!', command = start)
```

Comment: `player` is local variable inside those `chosenX()` functions.  If you want to update the global one, add `global player` at the beginning of those functions.  Also `hide_frames` inside those function does not execute `hide_frames()` because of the missing `()`.

Comment: Also, don't put `.pack()` on the same line you create `play_button` and `exit_button`; it can cause [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/16775594). Instead, use `play_button = Button(frame1, text = 'Play', command = playy)`, and then put `play_button.pack(side=TOP)` on the next line.